# Join two tables in one list

Tags: java, mysql, sql, scenebuilder

I want to merge the contents of two tables into one list.I'm new to programming and I am working on a school project.I need data from two tables to be shown in one table of the application. Current code works but if I have two rows in the database,the application table will be shown both rows twice, if I have three rows it will be displayed nine times and so on. I do not want repeats.I hope you understand my question to you.

I have this in my model:

```
public static ObservableList<archivesModel> takeArchives () {
        ObservableList<archivesModel> archives = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        try {
            Base.connect();
            PreparedStatement st= connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM destination,rent");               
            ResultSet rs= st.executeQuery();               
            while (rs.next()) {    
                archivesModel z;
                z = new archivesModel(
                        rs.getString(FIRST_DESTINATION),
                        rs.getString(LAST_DESTINATION),
                        rs.getInt(AMOUNT),
                        rs.getString(FIRST_DATE),
                        rs.getString(LAST_DATE));
                archives .add(z);                   
            }
            Base.disconnected();                
        } catch (SQLException ex) {Logger.getLogger(archivesModel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return archives;
    }
```

And in my controller I have

```
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        ObservableList<archivesModel> data = archivesModel.takeArchives();

        first_destination.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<archivesModel, String>("first_destination"));
        last_destination.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<archivesModel, String>("last_destination"));
        amount.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<archivesModel, Integer>("amount"));
        first_date.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<archivesModel, String>("first_date"));
        last_date.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<archivesModel, String>("last_date"));

        archivesRentTbl.setItems(data);
    }
```

Comment: Is there any connection or relation between those two tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to consider the relations between those two tables as well. 
Assuming that both tables have the key "rent_id" you could JOIN both tables using the following sql query:

```
SELECT * FROM destination a JOIN rent b ON a.rent_id = b.rent_id
```